# how to save a scala map as a table and also store the table into a file

Tags: scala, dictionary, save

How to save a map as a table.I get a map,now I want to save the map as a table and store the table into a file, how can I achieve it.The language is a scala.

Comment: Kindly elaborate your question. Explain your "map"? is it a data-map? a visual map of e.g SVG, or "flot" ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. In order to see a better answer, I would suggest you to further illustrate your question, provide enough example, eg, why you want to `save the map as a table`? what is the sample data and how it looks like (in both `map` and `table`)? what is the output file format? And the most important thing is, share your thought to people to allow people to make improvement on your idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by table a csv format (in this case without header), for

```
val m = Map("key1" -> 1, "key2" -> 2 )
```

try

```
// Make array of strings from map using string interpolation
val str = for ( (k,v) <- m) yield s"$k\t$v"  

// Create file writer
val pw = new java.io.PrintWriter(new File("table.csv"))  

// Write each map entry in new line and close
try pw.write(str.mkString("\n")) finally pw.close()
```

**Update**

Use a for comprehension for *flattening* a `Map` onto `List`,

```
val mxs = Map("key1" -> List(1,11), "key2" -> List(2,22) )

val str = for ( (k,xs) <- mxs; x <- xs ) yield s"$k\t$x"
```

Comment: thanks your answer solve my question,but when the map's value is list , how to store it into a table. such as ,Map map(key, ListBuffer(2,3,4))?  I want to save it as (key ,2), (key ,3 ) (key ,4). other than (key, ListBuffer(2,3,4))

Comment: @CaizhengLiu please note update.

Comment: thanks, it works .